# Laravel Framework 8.83.7 Vue ui is not installing properly on my new project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I can't seem to be able to install vue to my laravel

This is the steps I do:

1. run `composer require laravel/ui`
2. Install Vue `php artisan ui vue`
3. Install Vue with auth `php artisan ui vue --auth`
4. run `npm install && npm run dev`

The error I encounter

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: please do not post images of text.

Comment: opps.. sorry about that, should i copy and paste the error instead of posting image of text for better practice?

Comment: Yes, please. Update your question and post it as text. That'd make reading easier (i.e. on mobile) and also make this message searchable for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating vue if already installed

```
npm update vue-loader
```

To install you can use this

```
npm i vue-loader
```